# Monotouch CGAffineTransform, animate many Affine Transforms simultaniously on the same view

Tags: c#, ios, animation, xamarin.ios, cgaffinetransform

Let's say I have two animations that work individually, but I want them to work together simultaneously.

```
    public static void SlideAnimation( string name, UIView view, float xOffset, float yOffset, float duration )
    {           
        if ( view != null )
        {
            // ****** Begin Animation ****** //
            UIView.BeginAnimations(name + " SlideAnimation");
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(duration);
            UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (view);
            CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(xOffset, yOffset);
            CGAffineTransform transforms = move;
            view.Transform = transforms;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();  
            // ****** End Animation ****** //
        }
    }
```

And

```
    public static void GrowAnimation( string name, UIView view, float xScale, float yScale, float duration )
    {           
        if ( view != null )
        {
            // ****** Begin Animation ****** //
            UIView.BeginAnimations(name + " GrowAnimation");
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(duration);
            UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (view);
            CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(xScale, yScale);
            CGAffineTransform transforms = scale;
            view.Transform = transforms;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();  
            // ****** End Animation ****** //
        }
    }
```

The two functions above are of animations that both use CGAffineTransform   Let's say I want to execute them on the same view at the same exact time.  I want the result to be the view Sliding AND Growing simultaneously.

1.) My first attempt was calling one animation, and then immediately calling the next.  But that failed.  Basically, it began animating the first animation, but once it moved onto the next animation, it stopped the first one.  The result was only animating the second animation and completely skipping the first one...  Almost as if it can only do 1 animation at a time.

2.) My second attempt was calling each animation within it's own unique thread... This achieved the goal of making them animate simultaneously, but do I really need multithreading to do this?  There must be a better way...

PS:  Does the CGAffineTransform have some sort of group animation just like the CAKeyFrameAnimation has the CAAnimationGroup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create one transformation and add the second:

```
CGAffineTransform composite = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(xOffset, yOffset);
composite.Scale(xScale, yScale)
view.Transform = composite;
```